# Highcharts - Error bar change legend symbol

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to change the legend symbol for an errorbar chart? I have error bars for max and min values, overlapping a spline chart that displays the average value. I want the legend symbol for the min and max to be triangle and square but the series marker property doesn't have any affect. [spline with error bar](http://jsfiddle.net/g5w9kt1d/)

```
series: [{
        name: 'Average',
        type: 'spline',
        color: 'transparent',
        marker: { fillColor: '#2B767F', symbol: 'circle'},
        data: [33]
      },
      {
        name: 'Max',
        type: 'errorbar',
        color: '#2B767F',
        marker: { fillColor: '#2B767F', symbol: 'triangle'},
        data: [[33,68]],
        linkedTo: null,
        whiskerLength: 10
      },
      {
        name: 'Min',
        type: 'errorbar',
        color: '#2B767F',
        data: [[5,33]],
        linkedTo: null,
        whiskerLength: 10,
        marker: { fillColor: '#2B767F', symbol: 'square'},
      }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

I misunderstood the OP and provided workarounds for adding marker to errorbar series (it can be found after *END OF EDIT* header). The problem here is to add them to the legend instead.

**Workaround for markers in legend**

As I mentioned before: markers are not supported for error bars. The default 'big' circle symbol will be used as the legend marker.

The workaround here is to create the phantom scatter series with no data, but with proper marker definition. Then disable `showInLegend` for the original series and link it to the phantom one:

```
 // series
  {
    name: 'Max',
    type: 'scatter',
    color: '#2B767F',
    marker: {
      fillColor: '#2B767F',
      symbol: 'triangle'
    },
  }, {
    name: 'Max_',
    type: 'errorbar',
    color: '#2B767F',
    data: [
      [33, 68]
    ],
    whiskerLength: 10,
    showInLegend: false,
    linkedTo: ':previous'
  }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/1hLq2y5v/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.errorbar.linkedTo

**END OF EDIT**

---

Markers are not supported for error bars. It seems that there's a flaw in the API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.errorbar.marker.enabled

Enabling markers has no effect for error bar series.

**Workaround 1**

You can convert the boxplot to the **scatter** series (witch connected points): http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/yg36swfa/

```
  plotOptions: {
    scatter: {
      lineWidth: 1
    }
  }
```

**Workaround 2**

Use scatter only for whisker points. Set `whiskerLength` to `0` and place scatter points in the same positions. Disable legend and tooltip for this kind of series:

```
  plotOptions: {
    scatter: {
      showInLegend: false,
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: false
      }
    }
  }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/yeLeor1h/

This workaround seems to be better because it maintains the behavior of the tooltip.

Comment: Workaround 2 updates the plot point symbol but not the legend symbol - which is what I was looking for, thanks though.

Comment: I edited my post - now it contains a solution for the legend.

Comment: Scatter series with no data worked perfectly, thanks!